# Recursive function calls itself different number of times when tweaked even though both function does the same thing and produces the same result

Tags: python, recursion

```
def cc(amount, coins):
    lst = [0]
    denom = [1,5,10,20,50]
    def inner(amount, coins):
        lst[0] += 1
        if amount < 0:
            return 0
        elif coins < 1:
            return 0
        elif amount == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return inner(amount - denom[coins-1],coins) + inner(amount, coins - 1)
    x = inner(amount,coins)
    return lst[0],x # returns no. of calls and result

def cc2(amount, coins):
    lst = [0]
    denom = [50,20,10,5,1] # The only difference is the orientation of denom
    def inner(amount, coins):
        lst[0] += 1
        if amount < 0:
            return 0
        elif coins < 1:
            return 0
        elif amount == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return inner(amount - denom[coins-1],coins) + inner(amount, coins - 1)
    x = inner(amount,coins)
    return lst[0],x # returns no. of calls and result
```

The difference between the 2 function is that:
cc denom = [1,5,10,20,50]
cc2 denom = [50,20,10,5,1]

Index 0 = the number of calls to itself

Index 1 = result of the function

calling cc(100,5) vs cc2(100,5) it returns (17857, 343) and (43271, 343) respectively. I've tried calling  cc(150,5) and cc(50,5) and the results are similar in which cc2 calls the inner function many more times as compared to cc.

My question is why does this happen? My assumption is that the number of calls to itself should be around the same because the number of recursive branches is the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's simplify the situation by making `denom = [1, 2]` in the first example, `[2, 1]` in the second example. Consider the evaluation of `inner(2, 2)`.

For the first function:

```
inner(2, 2)
inner(0, 2) + inner(2, 1)
1 + inner(2, 1)
1 + (inner(1, 1) + inner(2, 0))
1 + ((inner(0, 1) + inner(1, 0)) + inner(2, 0))
1 + ((1 + inner(1, 0)) + inner(2, 0))
1 + ((1 + 0) + inner(2, 0)) = 1 + (1 + inner(2, 0))
1 + (1 + 0) = 2
```

For a total of 7 calls to `inner`.

For the second function:

```
inner(2, 2)
inner(1, 2) + inner(2, 1)
(inner(0, 2) + inner(1, 1)) + inner(2, 1)
(1 + inner(1, 1)) + inner(2, 1)
(1 + (inner(-1, 1) + inner(1, 0))) + inner(2, 1)
(1 + (0 + inner(1, 0))) + inner(2, 1)
(1 + (0 + 0)) + inner(2, 1) = 1 + inner(2, 1)
1 + (inner(0, 1) + inner(2, 0))
1 + (1 + inner(2, 0))
1 + (1 + 0) = 2
```

For a total of `9` calls to `inner`.

The driver behind the inefficiency is that we are forced to evaluate `inner(1, 1)` in the second case, even though it must be zero because `1` is not a multiple of `2`. That is the main driver behind the inefficiency.

Imagine if we were to calculate `cc(8, 2)` using the second method. We would be forced to calculate `cc(7, 1)` recursively, wasting a tremendous amount of work, even though we know that `cc(7, 1)` will equal `0` ahead of time.

The real trick is trying to avoid making any call which we know ahead of time will evaluate to `0`. This works out better in the first case than it does in the second because we can't overshoot `0`.

Comment: Hey I think I got it

Let me know if I'm getting it wrong.
cc2 requires me to evaluate cc2(49,1) .... cc2(1,1) (where 1 is 50 cents) even though all of these hit the base case amount < 0
whereas cc doesn't hit the base case amount <0 as much because the 1 in cc(x,1) reduces the amount by 1.

Thanks for the answer.